# How do I get the attributes for a model in PHP Active Record?

Tags: php, activerecord, phpactiverecord

I want to create a new record for a model.

I would like, instead of manually specifying every field for the model, to instead iterate over the list of fields of the model, and pull the values from the post hash if they are there

e.g. (is this possible?)

```
  $fields = Address::attributes()  // what is the actual name of this method?
  foreach($fields as $field) {
     if($_POST[$field) {
       $input[$field] = $_POST[$field];
     }
  } 
  Address::create($input);
```

Comment: Have you tried doing this (but fix the error in your code first if($_POST[$field])

Comment: Good point about using the guard - I get PHP notices otherwise. What I do now is create a string like "address address2" (all the fields I need for example). Then I split on the white space and iterate over them. I'd rather not do that though because I could for refactoring reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I use when the HTML form fields are the same as the database fields.

```
if( isset($_POST['Submit']) && $_POST['Submit']=="Save") {
  $p = $_POST;
  $flds = ""; $dta=""; $tbl='dummy';
  foreach ($p as $key=>$value) {
    if( strpos("Submit ",$key) === false ) {
      if( $flds != "" ) { $flds .= ","; $dta .= ","; }
      $flds .= $key;
      $dta .= $db->escape($value);
    }
  }
  $sql = "INSERT INTO $tbl (".$flds.") VALUES (".$dta.")";
  $db->query($sql);
}
```

Comment: Seems like here the independent variable is the $_POST and the dependent variable are the database fields right? I would like to do the opposite : independent variable are database fields, dependent variable are what $_POST fields I access. This way I only get the post fields that are relevant to the model.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a procedure for this using Reflection. This was originally written for a Codeigniter project, but should translate well to any php-activerecord project with very little tweaking.

```
public static function RoutePostToModel(&$model) {

    $refClass = new ReflectionClass(get_class($model));

    if($refClass->isSubclassOf("ActiveRecord\\Model")) {

        /* This is a subclass of ActiveRecord\Model. */

        $columns = $model->attributes();

        foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
            if(array_key_exists($key, $columns)) {
                $model->$key = $value;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Whenever you want to fill your model with post data, just do something like this:

```
$example = new ExampleModel();
RoutePostToModel($example);
$example->save();
```